# Поясните, почему отсутствует запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какому правилу пунктуации в следующем предложении отсутствует запятая между словами "ощущений" и "Лариосику"?

> Происходило это потому, что после катастрофы, потрясшей Лариосикову нежную душу в Житомире, после страшного одиннадцатидневного путешествия в санитарном поезде и сильных ощущений Лариосику чрезвычайно понравилось в жилище у Турбиных.

Comment: Если вы хотите ее там поставить, то должны указать причину постановки. Понимаете, объяснять надо, почему запятая (или иной знак) *ставится*, а не почему он *отсутствует*.

Answer (score 1):

"Упростим" предложение: уберем причастный оборот, относящийся к одному из однородных дополнений ("после катастрофы"), а также сопутствующие им определения.

Получим сложноподчиненное предложение в таком виде:
**Происходило это потому, что после катастрофы, после путешествия и ощущений**(?) **Лариосику чрезвычайно понравилось в жилище у Турбиных.**

Имеется ряд однородных дополнений: *после катастрофы, после путешествия и* [после] *ощущений*. Запятая в указанном месте (после последнего дополнения) никоим образом не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что нет причин для её постановки. ... ***потрясшей Лариосикову нежную душу в Житомире*** обособленное определение, выраженное причастным оборотом, стоящим после определяемого слова, а ***после страшного одиннадцатидневного путешествия в санитарном поезде и сильных ощущений*** не является оборотом, не является уточнением или пояснением. Это просто однородные члены ***после катастрофы, после путешествия и ощущений***. Запятые ставятся между однородными членами, а не после них.

Всё верно:

*Происходило это потому, что после катастрофы, потрясшей Лариосикову нежную душу в Житомире, после страшного одиннадцатидневного путешествия в санитарном поезде и сильных ощущений Лариосику чрезвычайно понравилось в жилище у Турбиных.*